# Why do Mighty Blow and Massacre not always give experience point bonuses?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've noticed that sometimes I'll get notices that I achieved a Massacre or a Mighty Blow, but without the bonus experience that normally goes with it.

What causes me to miss out?  I know it is typically only a small bonus, but every bit helps on the road to Inferno....

Comment: Why do you think you're not getting the experience?

Comment: Normally the message is "Mighty Blow: 18 enemies killed. 180 XP Bonus."  However, sometimes I get the message without the "*x* XP Bonus" part.

Comment: Could it be that you're killing trivial foes that aren't awarding any experience to begin with?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz That could be... I'm level 32 in Act IV, but there are a lot of those little weak shadow creatures around... not sure if I get XP for them normally or not.  I certainly get XP from most of the foes in the area, though.

Comment: I have the same thing but it only started when I was playing act 1 again with a friend.  He was level 1 and I was level 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've paid attention to when this happens, and the only situations I've encountered in which these streaks award no XP is in bossfights or events, where the minions you slay are summoned as a part of the event/bossfight, and award no XP at all.

Since you mention that this has in fact happened to you outside of any kind of event or bossfight, I think it's reasonable to assume that this applies to monsters which award no XP in general.

This shouldn't apply to monsters which are simply much weaker than you, since you can, for example, go back to Act 1 with a level 30 character and still get Massacre and Mighty Blows which award XP just fine.

Comment: That was what I thought at first as well, as I first noticed it during some events, but it definitely has occurred outside of boss fights and other special events. However, I think you are correct about it being in situations where the monsters don't normally count for XP.